# How to override all classes within in a media query?

Tags: css, overriding, media-queries

I am building a custom `.css`, but I do not know, how to override a bunch of classes within a media query with `"nothing"`. Means, I do not want this in my output, but also I don't want to delete this from the `css` as it needs to stay original. I also don't want to copy the whole bunch of classes and write `"none"` or `"unset"` behind every single attribute. Is there any solution for this. Thanks a lot.

```css
/*original.css*/
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 720px) {
    ol.accord li {                      
        width: 100%;          
    }

    .content {
        height: 149px;                          
        width: 50%;       
    }

    ol.accord li h3 {
        height: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        border-right: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
        padding: 7px 10px;
    }
}

/*custom.css*/
/*here should be nothing like it wouldn´t even exist in the original*/
```

Comment: if you don't need them , why don't you just delete them ? comment them out ? 'it needs to stay original ' what does that mean ? If you can't delete/comment them out the only solution i can think of is that you need to overwrite every single one of those styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can write as many classes in the media query within the parenthesis.
Here is an example for this

Just define the class above and change as per your requirement as per screen size.

```
.custom_class1 {
  height : 1px;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 720px) {
    ol.accord li {                      
        width: 100%;          
    }

    .content {
        height: 149px;                          
        width: 50%;       
    }

    ol.accord li h3 {
        height: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        border-right: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
        padding: 7px 10px;
    }
    .custom_class1 {
      height:70px;
  }
   .custom_class2 {
      height:70px;
   }
}
```